# How to prevent str_replace() to replace strings twice?

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace specific url parts with PHP on website init. So the `str_replace` is called on each website request.

Lets say this is my string:`/wp-content/plugins/app/creator/`

I want to replace

`/wp-content/plugins/app/`

with

`https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/`.

To replace this part of the string I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
str_replace('/wp-content/plugins/app/', 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/', '/wp-content/plugins/app/creator/');
?>
```

This works for the first time. I get the url I need. But on the second request I get something like:

`https://www.example.comhttps://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/creator` because the string I search for is still there. How could I fix this, so that the str_replace does not replace these strings twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead:

```
<?php

$str = '/wp-content/plugins/app/creator/';
$pattern = '/^\/wp-content\/plugins\/app\//i';

$x = preg_replace($pattern, 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/', $str);
$x = preg_replace($pattern, 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/', $x);
$x = preg_replace($pattern, 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/', $x);
echo $x;
// https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/creator/
```

This way, we make sure that we are only replacing a text that is "starting" with that string.

Answer (score 0):

You want [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) that will allow you to use regex to only select phrases at the beginning of the string (`^`). Most regexes use `/` for the separator, but using ticks here make it easier to read.

```
$str = '/wp-content/plugins/app/creator/';
$str =preg_replace("`^/wp-content/plugins/app/`", "https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/", $str);
```

Comment: If I use a variable for this, vor example `"`^$direcory`"`, the entire content from the source file is gone. Can we use php variables in regex expressions?

Comment: You should be able to, but you may want to double-check the variables first. It shouldn't erase the entire content

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace instead, ^ from the regex meaning that is must begin with

```
print preg_replace('/^(\/wp-content\/plugins\/app\/)/', 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/app/', '/wp-content/plugins/app/creator/');
```